# MVC3 Razor Parser Error on For-loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, for-loop

I am a newbie in MVC3 Razor world. I get parser error message for following code in a view (cshtml):

```
@for ( Int32 i = 0 ; i < Model.JobFiles.Count ; i++) 
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobFiles[i].DisplayName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobFiles[i].DisplayName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobFiles[i].DisplayName)
    </div>
```

The parser error message (translated from german to english)

> "for" was not expected after the "@" sign. Within the code the
>   construct such as "for" must have no "@".

But if I remove the "@" I get compiler error, because variable i is not defined.

I need your help and hint for best practice to solve the issue. Thank you in advance.

PS: the code fragment on my first posting was wrong. It is edited now.

Comment: You should remove the "@" as you did, but where *is* `i` defined?

Comment: @kirk: sorry, my code fragment was wrong. It is very embarassing. I edited just now.

Comment: @MagB - there's nothing intrinsically wrong with this code. Does the compiler error definitely point to this part of the code - maybe the issue is further down or in a nested method call?

Comment: @timbo: the compiler error (i not defined) shows the line @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobFiles[i].DisplayName). But I will take a look again as soon as I am in office today. I will report it here again.

Comment: If I put @ on "for" and put my mouse over Int32 I can see tooltip that show its namespace "struct System.Int32". But if I removed the @ the Int32 is only common text. I am sure this causes the compiler error. I tried to add @using System.Int32 on the top of file, but the intellisense doesn't recognize. Nevertheless it can be built without error. It seems it solves the issue. But I want to know whether it is best practice in MVC3 Razor?

Comment: Sounds odd - I've tried to replicate here but I don't get any such issue. Does it make any difference if you use "var" "int" or "Int32"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution by myself: removing the @ from 'for' and put @using System on top of file.
Thx to ppl who tried to help me.